Custom Toolbar not working on self hosted version of TinyMCE
The toolbar line works on the non-self hosted version but the same line here doesn't change anything.
I have this:

tinymce.init({
selector: '#mytextarea',
license_key: 'gpl',
toolbar: 'bullist numlist undo redo styles bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify indent'
});

